# Zend_Mail_Part: Get number of attachments

Tags: zend-framework, imap, email-attachments, zend-mail

How can i find out that how many attachments a message has?

Is this method reliable?

```
$attachments = 0;
$msg = $mail->getMessage($msgno);
if($msg->isMultipart()){
    $parts = $msg->countParts();
    for($i=1; $i<=$parts; $i++){
        $part = $msg->getPart($i);
        try {
            if(strpos($part->contentType,'text/html')===false && strpos($part->contentType,'text/plain')===false)
                $attachments++;
        } catch (Zend_Mail_Exception $e) {}
    }
}
```

or this?

```
$matches = array();
$pattern = '`Content-Disposition: (?!inline)(.*)[\s]*filename=`';
$attachments = (string) preg_match_all($pattern, $storage->getRawContent($msgno), $matches);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to have attachments that are `text/html` or `text/plain`, so it may not be reliable in all cases.  If there is an attachment that is an HTML file for example, you could have this situation.

You may be better off checking the `content-disposition` of each mime part instead:

```
$attachments = 0;
$msg = $mail->getMessage($msgno);
if($msg->isMultipart()){
    foreach($msg->getParts() as $part) {
        try {
            if ($part->disposition == Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT || 
                $part->disposition == Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_INLINE)
                $attachments++;
        } catch (Zend_Mail_Exception $e) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Zend_Mail_Message::getParts does not exists. What about second method in my answer?

Comment: `Zend_Mail` extends directly from `Zend_Mime_Message` which does have `getParts()` so `Zend_Mail` inherits it.  I just tested that method and it worked.  In the above example, `$msg` must be a `Zend_Mail` object.  I'm not sure what the `$mail->getMessage` is doing, but maybe you can skip that if `$mail` is your `Zend_Mail` object.  Getting the raw body of a message may not be the best idea if the message is large or has big attachments.  See if you can get the above method to work.  If not give me more info on the variables, or I can post an example in a different context.

Comment: I used it and an exception comes like that `exception 'Zend_Mail_Exception' with message 'no Header with Name disposition or disposition found'` also my `$msg` object is of `Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap` so should I do?

Comment: @RohanKumar `Zend_Mail_storage` doesn't extend from `Zend_Mail` or `Zend_Mail_Message` so their functions differ.  If you call `Zend_Mail_Storage_Abstract::getMessage()` you get a `Zend_Mail_Message` object you can call `getPart()` on.  The full header name is called `Content-Disposition`, not just `disposition` so that may be why you are getting the exception.  It's also possible that there are no parts with this header so you probably need to handle that exception one way or another.

Comment: @drew010 `Zend_Mail_Storage_Abstract` is an `abstarct class` so that it can't call directly I tried it and it gives error like `Fatal error: Cannot call abstract method Zend_Mail_Storage_Abstract::getMessage()..`

Comment: Yeah but `Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap` extends from `Zend_Mail_Storage_Abstract` so you can just call `getMessage` on that object.